# How to get python API to access Smartsheet

Tags: python-3.x, smartsheet-api

I am following the [smartsheet API's python-sdk example](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/index.html?python#sdks-and-sample-code) to do some practice.

Below are my steps (using Python 3.4.4 on macOS 10.7.5):

1. installed the SDK package from their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk)
2. installed pip using `pip install smartsheet-python-sdk` in my  terminal
3. created a `.py` file and moved it into the SDK file

#### Issue

When I run it, I got following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/canny_aiyaya/Desktop/smartsheet-python-sdk-master/smartsheet/charity.py", line 5, in <module>
    import smartsheet
  File "/Users/canny_aiyaya/Desktop/smartsheet-python-sdk-master/smartsheet/smartsheet.py", line 28, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named 'requests'
```

#### Code in the .py file

```py
import smartsheet
ss_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(access_token)
ss_client.errors_as_exceptions(True)
```

#### Analysis

I looked for some possible solutions, and try to install requests on my terminal using `sudo pip3 install requests`, but it shows:

> No matching distribution found for requests

This is my first time trying to use API on Smartsheet, any supports/links/videos will very helpful.

Comment: the problem is solved now, but I now have a new problem

Comment: Did any answer solve your question, then consider voting/accepting. For a new problem ask a new question. If it is related and link it here or this question there.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of dependencies. You can run `python setup.py install` from the Smartsheet SDK directory to install them.